# Can't boot from USB when installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu 11.10 32bit and put it in on USB drive using Universal USB Installer from http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ .

I then restarted my laptop. I pressed Esc and chose "Boot Management", but there was no option for booting from USB. The only options I could see were boot from hard drive and boot from internal CD/DVD. What should I do?

I have already changed the boot order at BIOS and it still didn't work.
My system is 64-bit, but does it matter if I want to install a Ubuntu 32-bit?

Comment: Question: Why 11.10? It would be better to use 12.04 (an LTS version), which will be supported for 5 years. Or 12.10 if you want to play with the latest versions and don't mind upgrading once or twice a year.

Comment: [LinuxLive USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) to make the bootable USB flash drive. Its work well and may enable you to boot the drive.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to try enabling "legacy USB support" in your BIOS then rebooting, then going in to the BIOS boot menu.

Another thing to try is to plug it into a different USB port, especially if you're currently plugging it into a hub or your computer separates its USB2/USB3 ports.

> My system is 64bit, but does it matter if I want to install a Ubuntu 32bit?

Nope, that should work fine, though if you have more than 3GB RAM (or are likely to upgrade RAM in the future) I'd highly recommend using 64-bit in order to use it more efficiently.